# Is the line color and thickness of the ArcGIS measure tool able to be customized?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, measurements

Is the line color and thickness of the ArcGIS measure tool able to be customized?

My searches have come up empty.
\
I'm working against a dark background and the black line (from the measuring tool) does not provide enough contrast to distinguish between the measure tool and the background.

Comment: can you change the background color temporarily while you are measuring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked in the usual places:

- ArcMap Options
- Customize Mode
- AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe

and cannot see anywhere to change this so I think you may need to submit an [ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas).

If you decide to do that you may want to target ArcGIS Pro (after checking whether it is already there) rather than ArcMap.